# Transfer data in different sheet from one to another by python

Tags: python

How to copy the data from a specific excel sheet to another excel sheet in different location, without affecting the column names and keeping the same format by python.

```
 import xlwings as xw

P1 = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\W1.xlsx'
P2 = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\W2.xlsx'

wb1 = xw.Book(P1)
wb2 = xw.Book(P2)

ws1 = wb1.sheets(1)
ws1.api.Copy(Before=wb2.sheets(1).api)
wb2.save()
wb2.app.quit()
```

This code actually create a new sheet in excel, but I want it to transfer in specific sheet without changing the header of the sheet, that has already existed.

Comment: please post the code you wrote

Comment: add your code to the question - you can edit your question

Comment: Ok I will update it, thank you.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl as xl

path1 = 'C:\\Users\\Xukrao\\Desktop\\workbook1.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:\\Users\\Xukrao\\Desktop\\workbook2.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb2.save(path2)
```